$\int_{\partial S}f(z) \mathrm{d}z; S=[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$

Let $f(z)= (1-\cos(z))/(z\sin(z))$, calculate $\int_{\partial S}f(z) \mathrm{d}z$  where $S=[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$ and its boundary is traversed in the counterclockwise direction.

$$\int_{\partial S}f(z) \mathrm{d}z=2 \pi i(\operatorname{Res}(0,f))=0$$ as $\operatorname{ord}(0,f)=\operatorname{ord}(1-\cos(z))-\operatorname{ord}(0,z\sin(z))=2-2=0$.
Is this well-justified? Any suggestions for explicitly showing that there is an analytic continuation of $f$ over $0$? If I only had $\frac{1-cos(z)}{z}$, I'd take the value $-\cos'(0)=0$ to be taken at $z=0$

It is correct. The only possible singularity of $f$ in $S$ is at $z=0$, where both numerator and denominator have a double zero, so that $f$ has a removable singularity.
Alternatively write
$$
 f(z) = \frac{1 - \cos(z)}{z \sin(z)} = \frac{2 \sin^2(z/2)}{2 z \sin(z/2) \cos(z/2)}
= \frac 12 \cdot \frac{\tan(z/2)}{z/2} 
$$
so that
$$
 \lim_{z \to 0} f(z) = \frac 12 \tan'(0) = \frac 12 \, .
$$
